# Compare two lists and return false if they are not equal scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

i would like to ask you for help to complete code below with condition which is testing if lists `ws` and `vs` are not equal. If they are not equal so return text `false(#f)` else process code below. I stared with fulfilling variables len1 and len2 which are counting length of both lists. When i run it i am getting this error: `lambda: no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in: lambda` What i am doing wrong?

```
(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (define (sub . vs)
    (let ((len1 (length ws)) (len2 (length vs)))
    (if (not (equal? (len1 len2) '#f))
    (foldl
     (lambda (i j res) (+ res (* i j)))
     0
     ws vs)))
   sub)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Count your parenthesis... they don't match.

Comment: I have corrected this part   `(if (not (equal? len1 len2)) #f )` but now when i put unequal input so it gives me this error `foldl: given list does not have the same size as the first list: (4)` so condition doesnot work like it should probably. Not very sure. I am pretty new in scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length` is almost always an anti-pattern in Scheme.

`length` is a *O(n)* operation, which is called twice, then you call another *O(n)* operation, `foldl`, resulting in a *O(3n)* process for `weighted-sum` - far from the ideal minimum *O(n)*. `foldl` is a nice candidate for many linear computations, but because of the length-matching requirement, you've created a bit of a square-peg-in-a-round-hole situation.

Using a named-`let` and `match*`, we write `weighted-sum` as a *O(n)* computation -

```scm
#lang racket

(define ((weighted-sum . ws) . vs) ;; curried form syntactic sugar 
  (let loop ((acc 0)
             (ws ws)
             (vs vs))
    (match* (ws vs)
      ;; both lists have at least one value
      [((list w ws ...) (list v vs ...))
       (loop (+ acc (* w v))
             ws
             vs)]
      ;; both lists are empty
      [((list) (list))
       acc]
      ;; any other case
      [(_ _)
       #f])))
```

Of course `match*` is a pretty fancy macro, so I'll show you how to rewrite `weighted-sum` using a simple `cond` expression. Get your logical reasoning hat ready: the *order* of the condition clauses is very important here -

```scm
(define ((weighted-sum . ws) . vs)
  (let loop ((acc 0)
             (ws ws)
             (vs vs))
    (cond
      ;; both lists are empty
      [(and (null? ws)
            (null? vs))
       acc]
      ;; at least one list is empty
      [(or (null? ws)
           (null? vs))
       #f]
      ;; inductive: both lists have at least one value
      [else
       (loop (+ acc (* (car ws)
                       (car vs)))
             (cdr ws)
             (cdr vs))])))
```

Both programs have the same output -

```
((weighted-sum 1 2 3) 1 2 3)
;; 14

((weighted-sum 1 2 3) 1 2)
;; #f

((weighted-sum 1 2) 1 2 3)
;; #f

((weighted-sum))
;; 0
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Sometime its probably better to use other conditionals function than `if`. Also checking if list is empty using `null?` looks easier than `equal?` function. Thanks a lot for explanation.

Comment: i have one more question regarding `#f` value what i would like to use if both lists are empty. I replaced `acc` with `#f` but looks like it is not working how i would expect.

Comment: O(3n) == O(n). You could write this without using `length` but in reality it doesn't change the time complexity. If you had `length` in the function of the `foldl` you'd have O(n²) which is common for simple solution of finding intersection of two lists while it can easily become O(n) too with a set.

Comment: @Sylwester you're right about O(3n) == O(n) but is there another quantitative way to talk about the differences between the two processes then? _"You could write this without using length..."_ isn't that what I showed? And even though the big-O representation would be O(n) for both, doesn't my implementation have a lower time complexity? Certainly the *actual* speed would be faster in measured...

Comment: @Fanhanes, scheme/racket is a functional language and part of writing functional programs is writing functions with well-defined inputs (domain) and outputs (codomain). The type of function you describe is bad, because even though the input is empty (`'() '()`), it is still valid, and should return a valid empty output (`0`). Of course, there's nothing stopping you from doing bad things, though. You could wrap the loop in `(if (and (null? ws) (null? vs)) #f (let loop ...))`.

Comment: Yes indeed, but you introduced a lot of housekeeping since it became roll your own recursion. OP was close to an optimum solution since it was more to the point. Usually with the same complexity the different implementation tend to favor different solutions so that kind of micro optimizations, at least premature as here, would not improve much. Eg. in adding an element to the end of a list simply revers + cons + reverse  is in some implementations faster than fancy tail recursion modulo cons which only uses half the space.

Comment: the problem with `length` is not 3n vs 1n, which is debatable anyway, but missing the  chance for an early bailout when one list is much shorter than the other. it could even be cyclic!

Comment: @Sylwester that's not a *micro* optimization.This answer creates a left fold which allows for args lengths mismatch. that's a valid design decision in its own right (e.g. Haskell does it that way). See also my comment above this one.

Comment: @WillNess I noticed the implementation will fail on different points, but since the job at each step is puny I don't think the time saving is enormous. If saving time is important though one might be tempted to get the length of the first list and use that length in the returned procedure. Now if you reuse `(weighted-sum 2 3 4 5)` in map it will recalculate `4` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Erase `))` after `#f` . Add `))` after `len1 len2)`, and it'll work. (not quite, but close<sup>(*)</sup>)

`#f` is self-evaluating, you don't need to quote it. Indent the `(foldl ...)` form which became a part of the `if` expression now.

Lastly, `(if (not A) #f B)` is the same as `(if A B #f)` is the same as `(and A B)`.

You are correct in checking that the *lengths* of both lists, the carried (sic) and the expected, are equal. I don't see why the lists *themselves* should be equal, though. They shouldn't, as far I can tell.

`(weighted-sum list-of-weights)` creates a procedure expecting a list of numbers to calculate its weighted sum using the previously supplied weights.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> The corrected code, after a few more fixes,  is:

```
(define (weighted-sum . ws)
  (define (sub . vs)
    (let ((len1 (length ws)) (len2 (length vs)))
      (and (equal? len1 len2)
        (foldl
          (lambda (i j res) (+ res (* i j)))
          0
          ws vs))))
   sub)
```

It is highly advisable to install e.g. Racket and use its editor to see and correct  the parentheses mismatches etc.

Comment: i tried your suggestion and i am getting error: `lambda: no expression after a sequence of internal definitions in: lambda`. Thats why i am confused with conditions at all because i tried many combinations and this one you suggested is not working looks like. Corrected code `(if (not (equal? (len1 len2))) '#f
    (foldl .....`