# Matching elements on a specific position of lists

Tags: list, pattern-matching, racket

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981108/compare-two-lists-and-return-false-if-they-are-not-equal-scheme) I would like to count the number of matches between the elements of two different lists of lists in a certain position.

For instance:

> '((a b **c**) (d e **c**) (f g h)) '((a e k) (l f **c**) (g p **c**))

would return 2 whenever we specify the *matching position* as the **third** one on every list (no matter what the other positions contain).

Is there a function doing this operation? I cannot find it. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details - what are the input parameters for the procedure? Explain in words how did you obtain `2` as a result in the given example. And the most important part: what code have you written so far? where are you having trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

I don't know of any readily made functions. So I wrote own.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; filter list of list by inner list element position
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define (position-filter lol pos)       
  (map (lambda (l) (list-ref l pos)) lol))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; intersect two lists (duplicate-preserved)
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; without duplicates would be `set-intersect`

(define (list-intersect l1 l2 (acc '()) (test equal?))
  (cond ((or (null? l1) (null? l2)) (reverse acc))
        ((member (car l1) l2 test)
         (list-intersect (cdr l1) (remove (car l1) l2) (cons (car l1) acc) test))
        (else (list-intersect (cdr l1) l2 acc test))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; intersect two position-filtered lols
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(define (lol-intersect-at-pos lol-1 lol-2 pos)
  (let ((l1 (position-filter lol-1 pos))
        (l2 (position-filter lol-2 pos)))
    (list-intersect l1 l2)))

;; you can count then how many elements are common by `length`
```

That's it.

**Testing**

Since I was too "lazy" to write lol with strings, I wrote a convenience function:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; convert lol elements to strings
;; convenience function
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(require racket/format) ;; for ~a
(define to-string ~a)

(define (as-strings nested-list (acc '()))
  (cond ((null? nested-list) (reverse acc))
        ((list? (car nested-list))
         (as-strings (cdr nested-list)
                     (cons (as-strings (car nested-list))
                           acc)))
        (else
         (as-strings (cdr nested-list)
                          (cons (to-string (car nested-list))
                                acc)))))
```

Equipped with this, we can try out lols with symbols:

```
(lol-intersect-at-pos '((a b c) (d e c) (f g h)) 
                      '((a e k) (l f c) (g p c)) 
                      2)
;;'(c c) ;; length is 2
```

lols with numbers as elements:

```
(lol-intersect-at-pos '((1 2 3) (4 5 3) (6 7 8)) 
                      '((1 5 19) (18 7 3) (29 39 3)) 
                      2)
;;'(3 3) ;; length is 2
```

and lols with strings as elements:

```
(lol-intersect-at-pos (as-strings '((a b c) (d e c) (f g h))) 
                      (as-strings '((a e k) (l f c) (g p c))) 
                      2)
;;'("c" "c") ;; length is 2
```

even mixed lols:

```
(lol-intersect-at-pos '((a b c) (a b "c") (d e 3) (f g "3"))
                      '((d c c) ("a" "b" c) (1 3 3) (2 4 3))
                      2)
;;'(c 3) ;; length of that is 2
```

**More complicated Solution with sorting (requires conversion `symbol->string` with all its complications)**

Before that, I wrote this. I leave it for history.

```
#lang racket

(define (get-position-values lol pos)       ; to extract elements at pos in inner lists
  (map (lambda (l) (list-ref l pos)) lol))

; to determine all elements common between two lists
; set-intersect would remove duplicates, so I had to write an list-intersect
(define (list-intersect l1 l2 (acc '()) (test-equality equal?) (test-smaller <))
  (let ((lst1 (sort l1 test-smaller))
        (lst2 (sort l2 test-smaller)))
    (cond ((or (null? lst1) (null? lst2)) (reverse acc))
          ((test-equality (car lst1) (car lst2))
           (list-intersect (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2) (cons (car lst1) acc) test-equality test-smaller))
          ((test-smaller (car lst1) (car lst2))
           (list-intersect (cdr lst1) lst2 acc test-equality test-smaller))
          (else
           (list-intersect lst1 (cdr lst2) acc test-equality test-smaller)))))

; to determine all elements common between two list of lists at position pos
; transformer is the function applied to the extracted list elements (necessary when symbols are used,
; since symbols don't have a test-smaller test, only equality test, but sorting would improve performance ...
; so this function doesn't allow to mixup strings and symbols, because symbols would be converted to strings
; so indistinguishable from strings when applying equality test.
; if one wants better equality test, then one has to construct a more complex test-smaller test function which
; can handle strings, symbols, numbers etc. - and one needs also such a more complex test-equality function -
; and then the transformer can be the identity function.
(define (match-element-lol-pos lol-1 lol-2 pos (test-equality string=?) (test-smaller string<?) (transformer symbol->string))
  (let* ((l1 (get-position-values lol-1 pos))
         (l2 (get-position-values lol-2 pos))
         (sl1 (map transformer l1))
         (sl2 (map transformer l2))
         (commons (list-intersect sl1 sl2 '() test-equality test-smaller)))
    (values (length commons) commons)))
```

This you can apply then to your example pair of list of lists.

```
(match-element-lol-pos '((a b c) (d e c) (f g h)) '((a e k) (l f c) (g p c)) 2)
; 2 for third element of inner lists!
```

Which gives:

```
;; 2
;; '("c" "c")
```

List of lists with numbers as elements, one can call like this:

```
(match-element-lol-pos '((1 2 3) (4 5 3) (6 7 8)) '((1 5 19) (18 7 3) (29 39 3)) 2 = < identity)
;; 2
;; '(3 3)
```

List of lists with strings as elements, one calls like this.
For convenient reasons, I wrote a function `as-strings` which converts all elements in a nested list into strings. I was just too lazy to wrap `""` around each symbol ...

```
;; convert all list elements of any nested-list into strings
(require racket/format) ;; for ~a
(define to-string ~a)

(define (as-strings nested-list (acc '()))
  (cond ((null? nested-list) (reverse acc))
        ((list? (car nested-list)) (as-strings (cdr nested-list) (cons (as-strings (car nested-list)) acc)))
        (else (as-strings (cdr nested-list) (cons (to-string (car nested-list)) acc)))))
```

So this can be used then like this:

```
(match-element-lol-pos (as-strings '((a b c) (d e c) (f g h))) (as-strings '((a e k) (l f c) (g p c))) 2 string=? string<? identity)
;; 2
;; '("c" "c")
```